# Do you need to "close" .net Configuration

Tags: .net, configuration, configurationmanager

When you create a configuration object to manage .net configuration files, do you need to close the files.

I have an application with several .dll components.  Do I have to use a global config to avoid keep writing over changes being done by other .dll's to the same configuration file.

```
Public Shared config As System.Configuration.Configuration 
config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
....do config entries here.
config.save
```

Do I know need to close/dispose this config before making changes to the same configuration file from another module.

Comment: System.Configuration is a pretty big mess.  But not quite *that* bad, the EXE configuration is a big deal well before you use that method.

Comment: I wrote a good library for handling configuration, see https://github.com/aloneguid/config

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need to Close/Dispose. The [Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration.aspx) class returned by the [OpenExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration.aspx) static method doesn't implement [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) nor it has any `Close` method so your code is fine.